# Braintree transaction not going through PHP

Tags: php, android, transactions, braintree

> **ANSWER IS AT THE BOTTOM!!!!**

I have been following the Braintree documentation and so far everything has worked.

In my android app i call a PHP to create a token then i send the token to a different PHP to handle the transaction.

when the drop in ui pops up i use the 4111 1111 1111 1111 Visa card and 01/20 expiration

i think the error is happening when i try to do the transaction in the PHP

.

When i do this then i get an error:
[image]

Heres where i create the token:

```
<?php

require_once '/usr/lib/braintree-php-3.11.0/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('26pynhd867qvxrje');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('rc7wnnk6cubdkyne');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('0808387e3d27fddb6eb0715905693741');

echo($clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate());

?>
```

Here is the PHP where i want to finish the transaction:

```
<?php

require_once '/usr/lib/braintree-php-3.11.0/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('26pynhd867qvxrje');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('rc7wnnk6cubdkyne');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('0808387e3d27fddb6eb0715905693741');

$nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"]

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
  'amount' => $amount,
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
  'options' => [
    'submitForSettlement' => True
  ]
]);

?>
```

Android Code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = Menu.FIRST;
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();


public void payBill(){
    PayBillBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PayBillBtn);
    PayBillBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getToken();
                }
            }
    );

}

public void getToken(){
    //AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://myServerName/getToken.php", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        public String clientToken;

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(PayBill.this, "Couldn't create token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            Toast.makeText(PayBill.this, "Created token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            this.clientToken = responseString;

            PaymentRequest paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest()
                    .clientToken(clientToken)
                    .primaryDescription("Payment")
                    .secondaryDescription("monthly bill for the month")
                    .amount(BillAmount)
                    .submitButtonText("Pay");

            startActivityForResult(paymentRequest.getIntent(PayBill.this), REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce = data.getParcelableExtra(
                    BraintreePaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT_METHOD_NONCE
            );
            String nonce = paymentMethodNonce.getNonce();
            // Send the nonce to your server.

            RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
            requestParams.put("payment_method_nonce", nonce);
            requestParams.put("amount", BillAmount);

            client.post("http://myServerName/nonceTransaction.php", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    Toast.makeText(PayBill.this, "Bill has been paid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    Toast.makeText(PayBill.this, "Payment hasn't gone through", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

********************************ANSWER BELOW*********************************

i was right, the PHP to send the transaction was wrong.

Heres the update, perfect code:

```
<?php

require_once '/usr/lib/braintree-php-3.11.0/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('26pynhz867wvxrjr');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('rc7wnnk6cybbkync');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('0808387e3d87fddb7eb0715905693741');

//$nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];
//$amount = $_POST["amount"]

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
'amount' => $_POST['amount'],
'paymentMethodNonce' => $_POST['payment_method_nonce'],
'options' => [
'submitForSettlement' => True
]
]);

?>
```